# How do you use a method parameter as a name for a new object?

Tags: python, class, methods

In this code I'm trying to create a portfolio object that has a method that will generate a new instance of the class `Stock` whenever a purchase is made. I would like that `Stock` object to have its ticker as its name/pointer.

So I actually would like it to be interpreted as `AMZN = Stock()` below, but I can't make this work. The output should be `3000`. I have tried different methods with no success so would be grateful for some advice. Quite new at this so might be some complications I'm not aware of...

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, ticker, price, amount):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount

# Create portfolio to hold stocks and available funds
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, funds):
        self.funds = funds
        self.stockPortfolio = []

    # Buying a stock and adding it to the portfolio
    def buyStock(self, ticker, price, amount):
        #Add stock to portfolio
        self.stockPortfolio.append(ticker)
        ticker = Stock(ticker, price, amount) # Would like this to be read as AMZN = Stock()
        return


p = Portfolio(100000)
p.buyStock("AMZN", 3000, 20)
print(AMZN.amount)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have `AMZN` be a member of the `Portfolio` object that you created? Consider the scenario where you have multiple portfolios all of which own AMZN stock. Whose AMZN holdings should `AMZN.amount` refer to?

Comment: Also, say I buy 20 shares of AMZN at 3000, and 20 more at 1500, Which of these purchases should it refer to? Should it instead give you a _list_ of `Stock` objects for that ticker?

Comment: `Portfolio` needs a better data structure in order to convey the information you want. One of many possible approaches is to use `self.stockPortfolio` as a dictionary, where the keys are the tickers, and the values are lists of `Stock` instances.

Comment: Doing what you would like is **not** a good idea. See [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you rather have `AMZN` be a member of the `Portfolio` object that you created? Consider the scenario where you have multiple portfolios all of which own AMZN stock. Whose AMZN holdings should `AMZN.amount` refer to?

Also, say I buy 20 shares of AMZN at 3000, and 20 more at 1500, Which of these purchases should it refer to? Should it instead give you a *list* of `Stock` objects for that ticker?

I suggest you define `Portfolio.stockPortfolio` as a `collections.defaultdict` object. Then, you can define a `__getitem__()` method of `Portfolio` to take the ticker symbol like `p["AMZN"]` and return the correct list from `stockPortfolio`. If you really want to allow access to the portfolio's holdings using attributes like `p.AMZN`, you could define the `__getattr__()` method. However, I strongly recommend you *don't* do this because of reasons given by @martineau in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214267/how-do-you-use-a-method-parameter-as-a-name-for-a-new-object/71214416#comment125880666_71214267) above: [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [Keep data out of your variable names.](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

```
import collections

class Stock:
    def __init__(self, ticker, price, amount):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Stock('{self.ticker}', {self.price}, {self.amount})"

# Create portfolio to hold stocks and available funds
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, funds):
        self.funds = funds
        self.stockPortfolio = collections.defaultdict(list)
        
# Buying a stock and adding it to the portfolio               
    def buyStock(self, ticker, price, amount):
        #Add stock to portfolio
        stk = Stock(ticker, price, amount)
        self.stockPortfolio[ticker].append(stk)    

    def __getitem__(self, ticker):
        return self.stockPortfolio[ticker]

    def __getattr__(self, ticker):
        return self.stockPortfolio[ticker]
```

I added a `__repr__` to `Stock` so that we can see what the stock objects in the lists contain.

```
p = Portfolio(100000)

p.buyStock("AMZN", 3000, 20)
print(p["AMZN"])
# Output: [Stock('AMZN', 3000, 20)]

p.buyStock("AMZN", 3500, 10)
print(p.AMZN)
# Output: [Stock('AMZN', 3000, 20), Stock('AMZN', 3500, 10)]
```

Comment: Your check for the already defined attributes in `__getattr__` isn't necessary, since that's the last step in the attribute search process. If an already existent attribute is being checked for, `__getattr__` will never get called, since the actual value will be found earlier in the process. Other than that small quibble, this is a great answer!

Comment: @Blckknght: The `__getattr__()` **is** necessary because an attribute with the stock's name is not being added to the class instance — it's being appended to one of the values of the `stockPortfolio` attribute of the class instance, so it will never be an "already defined attribute".

Comment: Right, I mean you don't need an exception in `__getattr__` for `funds` and `stockPortfolio`, those will be found *before* `__getattr__` is called.

Comment: @Blckknght good point, thanks for that. I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will read up on the links provided.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do what you want, but it's a pretty bad idea.

First, lets explain how to do it. You'll want to use the `globals()` builtin, which returns a dictionary to you holding all the global variables defined in the current module. If you edit the dictionary, the global variables will be changed. In your case, you want to add the `Stock` object as a value keyed by the `ticker` name. That would look like:

```
def buyStock(self, ticker, price, amount):
    #Add stock to portfolio
    self.stockPortfolio.append(ticker)
    globals()[ticker] = Stock(ticker, price, amount)  # make a global variable
```

Now that you know *how* to do it, here's why you probably shouldn't. The problem with using the global namespace like this is that you can't (easily) write code that expects a given stock ticker variable to exist. A line like your `print(AMZN.amount)` will fail if you bought a different stock instead. Similarly, if you buy another batch of Amazon shares, you'll overwrite the `AMZN` variable with a new `Stock` object, and will have lost track of how much your first purchase was of, and what price you paid for it.

A much better idea is to put the stock objects into a data structure, such as the list you have in your portfolio already. That way you don't need to use a specific name for it, and you can have more than one stock purchase with the same name, if necessary. I'd use something like this:

```
def buyStock(self, ticker, price, amount):
    #Add stock to portfolio
    self.stockPortfolio.append(Stock(ticker, price, amount))
```

You could print the amount of your latest purchase with `print(p.stockPortfolio[-1].amount)`, or write a loop to print out all the stocks (and their amounts or values, maybe) instead of always just getting the first one.